# How to check if DOM textnode is a link

Tags: javascript, dom

What's the best way of checking if a DOM textnode is a link? This following code checks if the node is immediately wrapped in an anchor tag, but wouldn't work if the  tag is further up the tree...

```
if (myTextnode.parentNode.tagName !== 'A') {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just climb up the tree.

```
var curNode = myTextnode;
while (curNode) {
   if (curNode.tagName == 'A')
      return true;
   else
      curNode = curNode.parentNode;
}
return false;
```